# knockout validation on a dynamic form using mapping

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

I'm trying to do a validation on dynamic form since some days and I can't get it.
I would apreciate your help a lot.

I need to extend the ViewModel's properties with the information received from the web service.
I have tried to personalize the mapping, but in checkboxes cases, enters once from every value of the array. Furthermore, in radios and checkboxes cases, only must be applied the needed attribute in the first of them, just only to appear once the validation message.

```
var answerMapping = {
    "values": {
        create: function(options) {                    
            var answer = ko.observable(options.data);                        
            answer.extend({
                required: {
                    onlyIf: function () { return (options.parent.required() === true); }
                }
            });     
            return answer;
        }
    },  
    "value": {
        create: function(options) {                    
            var answer = ko.observable(options.data);                        
            answer.extend({
                required: {
                    onlyIf: function () { return (options.parent.required() === true); }
                }
            });     
            if (options.parent.type() === 3) {
                answer.extend({ number: true, min: options.parent.min, max: options.parent.max });
            }
            if (options.parent.type() === 4) {
                answer.extend({ dateISO: true });
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
};
```

You can see sample in jsfiddle before customize mapping:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rferreiraperez/Y9yR8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your fiddle.

The main problem is that the `required` validator cannot be used like this for an observable array (it seems it only checks if the content is null, not if the array is empty).

You can use this custom validator instead:

```
ko.validation.rules['requiredNonEmpty'] = {
    validator: function (val, other) {
        console.log(val);
        return val !== null && val.length > 0;
    },
    message: "Required non empty"
}
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

Other problems included:

- `values` declared as `observable` instead of `observableArray`
- some missing parenthesis (for the `min` and `max`)
- the grouping was not deep (`myVM.errors = ko.validation.group(myVM, {deep: true});`)

If you want to display the message for the `values` observableArray, add the following:

```
<span data-bind="validationMessage: values"></span>
```

### Update

You are right. The problem is that `values: { create: function(options) {} }` is called for each value in `values: ["A1", "A2"]` but not for the whole array.

You have to add the validation after the mapping :(

Like this:

```
self.load = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, answerMapping, self);
    for (var i = 0; i < self.questions().length; i++) {
        var question = self.questions()[i];
        if (ko.isObservable(question.values) 
            && question.values() instanceof Array) {
            question.values.extend({
                requiredNonEmpty: {
                    onlyIf: function () { return (question.required()=== true); }
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

And remove the `values` part in the mapping.

### [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/Y9yR8/18/)

Comment: Thank you very much, but... the message "required non empty" never is showed, furthermore if the variable "values" has an initial value, for exampe ["A1","A2","A3"] the questionnaire does not charge correctly.